# 24 V Door Bell Modification

Tags: diy, 24v

I'm looking to create a custom doorbell and am looking for advice. I am retrofitting a traditional 24 V doorbell system. My output I'm looking to get when you depress the doorbell is 5 short bursts of 24 V (5 taps essentially). So depress the doorbell button, you get 5 dings inside. Is this doable? Short burst of 24 V to output 5 dings on the bell. Is it more reasonable to do a repetitive ding as the button is depressed (24 V continuously resulting in a metered "ding.ding.ding.")? To clarify, it is the traditional 24 Vac button with a 24 Vac actuator to "ding" the bell.

Just looking for help since I'm stumped on the circuitry needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a job for an Arduino/any MCU and a MOSFET, but the devil’s in the details. Please draw a schematic and/or block diagram.

Comment: Definitely doable.  In many different ways.  You could use a microcontroller (as suggested by winny), or go old-school and use a geared motor and a couple of microswitches.  No electronics required.

Comment: I'm definitely looking for old school. I don't have the computer literacy to program Arduino (love the idea, but sorry winny). Gear and motor sounds like a great idea Simon! Would putting in a capacitor be able to store enough 24 volt power to run the motor for 1-2 seconds off of one depression? Sorry for the illiteracy, I'm a DIY guy just trying to bring an idea to fruition.

Comment: You need to _edit your question_ a bit.  Is it the (typical) 24 volts **AC**?  Does it have the (typical) two wires going to the button?  Does it have the (typical) mechanical chime assembly, with electromagnets actuating the striker(s)?  I assume the answer to all of these is "yes", but it does have some bearing on the ultimate answer.

Comment: Tim, updated. You are correct. The answer is yes to all of those.